# Error making a condition on a component in React.JS

Tags: reactjs

I have this following component in my application:

```
import React from 'react';


function CriandoParametros (props){

    const status = props.nota >= 6 ? 'Aprovado' : 'Reprovado';
  
    const frase =  <p>O aluno <strong>{props.aluno}</strong> recebeu a nota: <strong>{props.nota}</strong> e está <span id="resultado">{ status }</span></p>;

    if(props.nota >= 6){
        document.getElementById("resultado").style.color = '#008000';
      }else{
        document.getElementById("resultado").style.color = '#FF0000';
      }

    return(
        <div>
            <hr />
           {frase}
        </div>
   
       )
  

}

export default CriandoParametros;
```

And in my index.js file I'm bringing this component as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import reactDom from "react-dom";
import './index.css';
import Menu from './components/basicos/header';
import Rodape from './components/basicos/footer';
import CriandoParametros from "./components/basicos/ComParametros";

const subtitulo = <h3>Empresa de Engenharia</h3>


reactDom.render(
    <div>
        <Menu></Menu>
        <h2>Fazendo um teste para Engesin</h2>
        { subtitulo }

        <CriandoParametros aluno="Andrêy Ferraz" nota="8.5"/>

        <CriandoParametros aluno="Jose Pereira" nota="5.5"/>

        <Rodape></Rodape>
    </div>
    , document.getElementById("root"));
```

This is giving me the following error:
[image]

How can I resolve this? I'm starting now as React.JS!

Comment: The code using `document.getElementById` runs *before* the first render. So it returns `null` and `null.style` breaks.

Comment: There's ways to make the code not break, but modifying the style directly through the DOM like that is an anti-pattern anyway. Use the `style` prop instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use `useEffect` hook when manipulation DOM, it will save you lot of pain also it's good practice
As Brian mentioned it's a antipattern to manipulate dom when it's not necessary

Updated Code:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'; //modified


function CriandoParametros (props){
  //modification - start
   useEffect(() => {
        const el = document.getElementById("resultado");
        if(el) el.style.color = props.nota >= 6 ? '#008000' : '#FF0000';
   }, [props.nota])
  // end
    const status = props.nota >= 6 ? 'Aprovado' : 'Reprovado';
  
    const frase =  <p>O aluno <strong>{props.aluno}</strong> recebeu a nota: <strong>{props.nota}</strong> e está <span id="resultado">{ status }</span></p>;

    

    return(
        <div>
            <hr />
           {frase}
        </div>
   
       )
  

}

export default CriandoParametros;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know I could do this, as I said I'm learning. Thank you very much, it helped a lot!

Comment: But even so the error still occurs: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression. (7:4).

Comment: document.getElementById("resultado")?.style.color

remove `?` from here.

Comment: ```
useEffect(() => {
       const el = document.getElementById("resultado");
       if(el) el.style.color = props.nota >= 6 ? '#008000' : '#FF0000';
   }, [props.nota])

```

replace your code with this ^^

Comment: The error disappeared, only the condition is not working properly.

Comment: Can you give more information ? what condition.

Comment: The "if" is not working correctly, the color is being applied to the first item only.

Comment: I understand the cause of the error, this is because in my index file I'm repeating the same component. How would I be able to apply this condition having to repeat the component to provide more data?